# Official end of support for PHP4?

Tags: php, php4

Is there an official date for when support for PHP4 will end?

I keep reading this date and that on various sites and blogs, but can't find anything on the PHP website.

Am I  overlooking something?

Comment: http://php.net/eol.php -- lists obsolete branches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP4 is already way past the support.  I think support ended more than a year ago.

Comment: You're right, I thought I read August *2009* as the last entry in the changelog but it was 2008.

Answer (score 10):

[Support was officially discontinued on 2007-12-31!](http://www.php.net/releases/#v4)

Answer (score 5):

PHP4 was no longer developed since 2007-12-31, although some security issues were still taken care of up until 2008-08-08. Just before that, the latest version of PHP4 was released, being PHP 4.4.9.

Also interesting for those still supporting PHP4: MySQL 4.0 support has ended as of 2008-12-31, and MySQL 4.1 support will end at 2009-12-31.

Please note that some distributors still "support" PHP4, like Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4.
But actually there is no valid argument for still using PHP4, it's so old that only people with NO maintenance budget will need it.

Answer (score 4):

The [support for PHP 4 was ended at the end of 2007](http://www.php.net/archive/2007.php#2007-07-13-1). Only security fixes were made until 2008-08-08.

Answer (score 4):

Development snaps of PHP6 are available.

http://snaps.php.net/