# Getting "Parse error" from server in "recaptchalib.php"

Tags: php

I'm implementing a Google reCHAPTCHA form and I guess the PHP version is 4 on the server, because I'm getting errors, like

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in /web/htdocs/---SITE---/recaptchalib.php on line 7

So because it does not recognize the PHP 5-only `protected` keyword, I'm getting errors. Can someone help me resolve this. There is no PHP4 version for the `recaptchalib.php`? Or I can change the PHP headler in the `.htaccess` file, but if the server is not supporting it?

Comment: Why are you still using PHP 4? That version is very old, has had numerous bugs resolved, has had numerous performance additions, and should be considered dead. http://php.net/eol.php

Comment: Is not my server! and is not my decision :(

Comment: Tell whoever is running it to upgrade. This is just problem 1 of tons you will encounter, and if spam bots are your problem, wait until you run into malicious bots.

Comment: So there is no other solution?

Comment: No good solution, everything your going to do is a hack. You could modify the Google code to use PHP 4 functions (for example `fopen, fread, fclose` instead of `file_get_contents`), even that might fail though if they require some new technology that didn't exist in 2005ish when that was released. Editing the source code of an API is not good practice.

Comment: I understand, but what to use instead of `private function _encodeQS($data)` ??

Comment: I agree here with @chris85 . And as for your last question in comments, you have to remove the `private` word and read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247092/how-to-make-a-class-property-private-in-php4/2247114#2247114

Comment: I removed the `private` word and now I'm stuck on this code part: `$getResponse = $this->_submitHttpGet(
            self::$_siteVerifyUrl,
            array (
                'secret' => $this->_secret,
                'remoteip' => $remoteIp,
                'v' => self::$_version,
                'response' => $response
            )
        );` what I can change here to not getting the `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '('` error?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, php 4 doesn't have this syntaxe: `self::` everything defined this way will break...