# Sanitizing user input that will later be e-mailed - what should I be worried about?

Tags: php, forms, email-validation, sanitize

I'm interning for an NGO in India (Seva Mandir, http://sevamandir.org) and trying to fix their broken "subscribe to newsletter" box. Because the staff isn't very sophisticated and our web host isn't great, I decided to send the relevant data to the publications person via mail() instead of storing it in a MySQL database.

I know that it's best to treat user input as malicious, and I've searched the SO forums for posts relevant to escaping user data for sending in a mail message. I know the data should be escaped; what should I be worried about and what's the best way to sanitize the input before emailing it?

Also note that the org's web host is still using PHP 4, so I can't just use filter_var for strings. I'm [working with them to fix the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744124/intern-working-for-indian-ngo-help-with-php-4-advising-staff), but for now I'd have to use regexes or strip_tags or some other method.

Form flow:
1. User enters email on homepage and clicks Submit
2. User enters name, address, more information on second page (bad usability, I know, but my boss asked me to) and clicks "Submit"
3. Collect the data via $_POST and email it to the publications editor (and possibly send a confirmation to the subscriber).

I am going to sanitize the email in step 2 and the other data in step 3. I appreciate your help,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be aware of [Email Header Injection](http://www.nyphp.org/PHundamentals/8_Preventing-Email-Header-Injection) attacks.

Basically if you strip `\n` and `\r` from the from the `$name`, `$from`, `$to` and `$subject` you should be fairly safe, but it's always best to take a white list approach.

Comment: I used this code (from the link, for anyone who visits this question in the future):

function safe( $name ) {
   return( str_ireplace(array( "\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:", "bcc:","to:","cc:" ), "", $name ) );
}

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the user-entered email address to send a confirmation, ensure that they've only entered one email. A spammer can sneak line breaks, and therefore arbitrarily long `Bcc:` entries, into your message headers if you don't watch out.

See [email injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_injection).

Comment: Doesn't look like he's letting user enter a subject, but yes, anything destined for the headers better be clean.

Comment: I am using rfc3696 to sanitize the user's email input. All of the entries (name, email, etc) are going into the body of the email I send to the publication editor.

Answer (score 1):

As far I as I know, as long as you're using plain text and insert user entered data only into email body, there is nothing to sanitize.