# php.ini file not found

Tags: php, cpanel

I have a hosted website with cPanel. I want to modify `php.ini`, but I don't get where that file is on server. I tried to find the location of the file using `phpinfo()` and I got the location as `/usr/local/lib/php.ini` but when I search in file manager I'm unable to find this location.

I looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3401536/1989696 and followed the same steps, but I'm not sure how to tell if the webserver supports SSH or SFTP access.

Also, how can I locate the `php.ini` file?

Comment: Do you have a `Loaded Configuration File` entry in `phpinfo()'s` output?

Comment: Does `ini_set` and `ini_get` not help you achieve your goals? There should be rarely need to actually configure stuff in the -ini file.

Comment: no because i dont know how to set ini file using `ini_set` and `ini_get` .will you show me how to use `ini_set` and `ini_get`

Comment: `$ whereis php.ini` http://linux.die.net/man/1/whereis

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a dedicated or virtual server, you are not allowed to edit system-wide PHP settings.

If PHP runs as CGI, you'll possibly have a custom `.ini` file you can tweak:

[image: CGI]

... or, if your PHP version is 5.3 or greater, you can create your own [.user.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) files.

If PHP runs as Apache module:

[image]

... you can use good old [.htaccess](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php).

And, of course, 95% of the PHP settings can just be changed from within PHP code:

- [ini_set()](http://php.net/ini_set)