# Need suggestions for naming 2 classes in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, class, function

I have one class `user` that is initiated in `/update/user.php` when `update.php` is started. This class handles user related queries on the database, such as edit, delete, create, etc.

I'm in the process of creating a new class also named `user` in `/src/user.php` that will perform user related queries on the database but only to retrieve them (and output) them. Such as to retrieve their user id, usergroup, e-mail, etc.

I find the need to name them both `user` but obviously there will be conflicts when `update.php` is retrieved. What suggestions can you give for naming these two different classes, even though they are seperate areas in my library but perform similar operations?

Using PHP 4.

Comment: You should not under any circumstances be doing new development in a language considered dead by the developers for 2+ years.  That said, it also won't impact the answer to this question in any meaningful way...

Comment: I would love to upgrade to PHP 5.

Comment: You probably have compelling reasons why you can't switch to 5, but to reiterate because it's really important: PHP 4 is a dead horse, does not even get security hotfixes any more, and has much more limited OOP capabilities than 5. Learning PHP 4 from scratch in 2011 is *very* unusual. If your employer/client/whatever has a legacy production app running on 4, they really should consider switching it to 5 - especially if it's public-facing. It's usually not that painful.

Comment: My employer actually mentioned upgrading to PHP5 a few days ago. He hopes to upgrade (and move all of the legacy projects) to PHP5 in the next few months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they both query, but only one writes, then I would suggest something like.

```
UserWrite
UserRead
```

or

```
UserCreate
UserAccess
```

Comment: I have considered this, however `UserWrite` would only be initiated when I want to perform an operation on the user, which would occur much less than `UserRead`. That's why I have this pickle. I will definitely consider your suggestion.

Comment: I've opted for adding a prefix to the `user write` class, and leave the `user read` class to `user` for the time being. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Actually, could it be possible for `user write` to be a "sub class" of say, `update`? So if I wanted to create a new user, I would call `$update->user->create` instead of `$user->create`?

Comment: @Jazza, sure that makes sense too.

Answer (score 2):

To present an alternative to the whole naming *structure* instead of just suggesting names. The [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com) and other libraries have a naming structure that corresponds with the file's position in the tree. Half-fictitious example:

```
Class name               Is in
-----------------------------------------------------------
Zend_Auth                /Zend/Auth.php
Zend_Auth_Adapter        /Zend/Auth/Adapter.php
Zend_Auth_Helper         /Zend/Auth/Helper.php
Zend_Auth_Adapter_HTTP   /Zend/Auth/Adapter/HTTP.php
```

so the underscore is the directory separator, and the last element of the name is the PHP file's name.

The main reason for this is that it makes [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) extremely easy, but it's also a nice way for ordering libraries by task. Also, when you see a class used somewhere in your code, you can always tell *which file it is in* which is a great plus.

In your current method, the problem I see is that "src" is a very unclear description of what that class actually does. Maybe a more telling name (like "tools" or "query") would be in order, or maybe the main user  class and should just be named "user"?

Applying the abovementioned example to that structure could result in

```
Class name                   Is in
------------------------------------------------------------
MyAppname_User_Update        /User/Update.php
MyAppname_User               /User.php
```

Oh and, what @Charles says in his comment. You should absolutely not be developing for PHP 4 any more. It is a dead version, and is [no longer supported.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734072/official-end-of-support-for-php4)

Comment: agreed  , ZF naming convention is indeed pretty good one to adopt

Comment: Interesting naming convention. I wouldn't have considered it at all. I'm declined to use it though because I'm in a (long) learning phase of php, and my library's file structure changes often.

Comment: @Jazza I know what you mean, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question, but do you think that you really want to create 2 different classes to perform the same action? You can just create it in `/src/user.php` and obviously can use it wherever you want. You should make methods in that class in such a way that they will be used in both the problems. i.e in retrieving information and also in updating it.

Comment: Not really. I have split the two to keep them distinctly separate because although they operate on the same thing - users - they perform "opposite" functions.

Answer (score 0):

In OOP, your update.php is called BaseDAO.php and user.php is call UserDAO.php (Data Access Object). But since you don't use OOP, I guess use can name it BaseService.php and UserService.php

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create one class to create, edit, delete, and retrieve records related to the users. Then manage user Roles to limit the access to the methods, rather than creating two separate class for one object class.

Explanation with comparison to real world.

Let's say we have class Car. When user with Mechanical Role (or a mechanic) uses the car class then, he will able to access methods like `repair(), openHood()`, where as when users with driving role (or drivers) will access `drive()` methods.

In this scenarios also it is very inappropriate to create `CarMechanic` class and `CarDriver` class.

I think I made my point.